# Using nth-child to create alternating background colors in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, css-selectors

I have a WordPress loop that contains three post types (recipes, events, posts). My goal is to assign a background color of #e4dfce to every other post in the loop to the following class: .lb-wrapper

I currently have it working exactly how I want using the following code but I would like to use nth-child instead of nth-of-type.

`.recipe:nth-of-type(odd), .event:nth-of-type(odd), .post:nth-of-type(odd) .lb-wrapper {
    background-color: #e4dfce;
}`

I have tried this but it does not work:

`.lb-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e4dfce;
}`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you add the Wordpress (PHP) code that generates the loop?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code for the Loop is being generated by a plug-in so I cannot provide the PHP code, but here is the page that I am trying to make it work on: http://goo.gl/cIE4Wg

Comment: Try changing the `odd` for `2n` and create another class with the background-color you want and `2n+1`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it returned the same result as using odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mentioned below is fine can you provide a link to your website or a jsfiddle. This might just be a css conflict with other defined style

`.lb-wrapper:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #e4dfce; }`

Comment: this code isn't working because the element that you  are targeting `.lb-wrapper` aren't next to each other so nth-child odd or even won't work here. The work around would be to add some identifier class via your wordpress loop.

Answer (score 0):

The developer of the LoopBuddy plugin that I am using to create my WordPress loop provided the following solution to my problem:

```
.loop-content .hentry:nth-child(2n+1) {background-color: #e1771e;}
```

**Additional comments from developer:** *"You're not using the selector properly. Your code assumes that "inside the lb-wrapper class, there are several occurrences". However, you want to target all occurrences of the lb-post-wrapper class "inside" another class, such as the loop."*